# Parsley checkbox validate: can't get working

Tags: forms, validation, checkbox, parsley.js

Here's what I have, below, trying to use bits from similar answers here, plus items from the parsley site.. Nothing happens..User is not alerted that at least 1 box must be checked. Do I have this all wrong? Thank you in advance for any clues!

```
<form action="success.html" id="contact-form" data-parsley-validate>
  <label for="language">Please Choose your Language:<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="language" value="english" parsley-group="language" parsley-mincheck="1">English<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"  name="language" value="spanish" parsley-group="language" >Spanish<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"  name="language" value="french" parsley-group="language" >French 
</label>
```

Comment: Please add the _javascript_ tag to provide Syntax Highlighting to your question and the following answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have some problems with your code:

1. `parsley-group` doesn't exist. There is a `data-parsley-group` and is applicable if you want to validate a portion of your form.
2. `parsley-mincheck="1"` doesn't exist. There is a `data-parsley-mincheck="1"`.

Assuming that you require at least one language, but can accept more, this code should do the trick:

```
<form action="success.html" id="contact-form" data-parsley-validate>
    <label for="language">Please Choose your Language:<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="language[]" 
            value="english" required>English<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"  name="language[]" 
            value="spanish" required>Spanish<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"  name="language[]" 
            value="french" required >French</label>
    <button type="submit" id="submit-button">Submit form</button>
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
    // bind parsley to the form
    $("#contact-form").parsley();

    // on form submit, validate form and, if valid, show valid in the console
    $("#contact-form").submit(function() {
        $(this).parsley("validate");
        if ($(this).parsley("isValid")) {
            console.log('valid');
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

If you want the user to select one and only one option, I advice you to use radio buttons.